# scrapy css last-child selector fails to select text

Tags: html, css, scrapy

I'm trying to select/match elements in a HTML using CSS selector in a Scrapy framework. However, I got stuck at one of the fields that I wish to extract with the last-child selector.

Here is the HTML:

```
<td class="Table-Standard-AwardName Table-Scholarship-AwardName">

<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ScholarshipDataControl_grvScholarshipSearch_ctl02_hylScholarshipName" class="bold" href="/Scholarships/14123/Family-Bursary,-The">Family Bursary, The</a>   

<br>

<span>Field of Study:</span> 

EcologyEnvironmental Science

</td>
```

where the text "**EcologyEnvironmental Science**" is that I have to match.

When I use the last-child selector the output shows 'Field of Study':

```
In [3]: response.css('td.Table-Standard-AwardName.Table-Scholarship-AwardName > *:last-child::text').extract_first()
Out[3]: 'Field of Study:'
```

I have looked through the other questions and tried multiple ways like `nth-last-child() and combined sibling` selector, to no avail. Help!

Comment: Try `response.css('td.Table-Standard-AwardName.Table-Scholarship-AwardName > *::text')[-1].extract()`.

Comment: use xpath? response.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/text()')

Comment: Tried that, and the inspector-given `response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ScholarshipDataControl_grvScholarshipSearch"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()')` . Neither yielded an output.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: I tried that and other indices. Got `in __getitem__(self, pos)
     59 
     60     def __getitem__(self, pos):
---> 61         o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
     62         return self.__class__(o) if isinstance(pos, slice) else o
     63 

IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: @NatashaTing can you try without the last `>`, that would be  `response.css('td.Table-Standard-AwardName.Table-Scholarship-‌​AwardName *::text')[-1].extract()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's already been told, the `EcologyEnvironmental Science` text is part of the `td` element, that's why you only need to extract its text, try something like this:

```
values = response.css('.Table-Standard-AwardName.Table-Scholarship-AwardName::text').extract()
out = next(filter(None, map(methodcaller('strip'), values)))
# you can assign 'EcologyEnvironmental Science' to your item
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I haven't thought of calling it all out and filtering the output.

Comment: Great, please feel free to mark this question as answered if it helped you.

Comment: I was actually hoping to select using css/xpath/regex. In the HTML file that I work with, text in each `td` rows is very different so it'd be hard to find a common value to filter them. I kept looking around - there should be a selector for last `td` node. Thanks very much for the alternative you suggested though, if I don't get another working method within the next few days I'd mark this question answered.

Comment: I see, maybe you could update the question adding a couple more examples, so that we can add more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

"EcologyEnvironmental Science"  is not an  element (like a span, div or whatever), but simply part of the contents of that `td`. So it doesn't meet the condition `... > * ...` which means " any direct child of the `td` with that class.

You'd have to put it into a span to be able to select only that part of the contents via CSS, like

```
...
  <span>Field of Study:</span> 
  <span>EcologyEnvironmental Science</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Yeah, if I wrote the page I would have put that in a `span`. Is there a selector for the last content of `td` ?